# Сборка js-файла из es6 модулей с помощью gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6

Не нашел статьи, где достаточно просто объяснён процесс сборки javaScript-файла из ES6-модулей с помощью **gulp**. Задача данного вопроса - совместными усилиями задающего вопрос (т. е. меня) и отвечающих устранить данный пробел. Я упростил проект до минимума, но так, чтобы продемонстрировать возможности обмена данными между модулями.

---

### Структура проекта

**es2015** папка с исходными js-файлами стандарта **ES6** (**ES2015**).

**common.js** Все переменные и функции в данном файле должны быть доступны во всех модулях. На практике, в такой файл имеет смысл выносить некоторые функции общего назначения, константы, содержащие имена CSS-классов и ID и т. д.

**module_one.js** Работает с переменными и функциями из **common.js**, а также своими собственными (локальными) переменными и функциями, любые из которых на усмотрение разработчика могут быть экспортированы в другие модули.

**module_two.js** Использует функции и переменные из **common.js**, а также некоторые функции и переменные из **module_one.js**.

**js** папка с промежуточными js-файлами стандарта **ES5**, сконвертированных **gulp-babel**. Имена файлов сопадают с файлами папки **/es2015**.

**index.html** - файл с минимальной разметкой (просто чтоб было, что открывать в браузере)

**bundle.js** - собранный **gulp** продакшен-файл из файлов папки **/js**.

**gulpfile.js**

**package.json**

---

### Содержимое ключевых файлов

**common.js**

```
export const COMMON_CONST = 'Эта константа должна быть доступна во всех модулях.';

export function commonFunction(){
    console.log('commonFunction() отработала успешно. Такой же результат должен быть при вызове из любого модуля');
}
```

**module_one.js**

```
import * from "./common";

console.log(COMMON_CONST);
commonFunction();

var moduleAlocalVar = 'Эта переменная доступна только в этом модуле. А-ля "private"'.
export var moduleAexportableVar = 'Эту переменную планируется использовать в других модулях. А-ля public';

var moduleAlocalFunc(){
    console.log('Эта функция доступна только в этом модуле. А-ля "private"');
}

export moduleAexportableFunc(){
    console.log('Эту функцию планируется использовать в других модулях. А-ля "public"');
}
```

**module_two.js**

```
import * from "./common";
import {moduleAexportableVar , moduleAexportableFunc} from "./module_one.js";

console.log(COMMON_CONST);
console.log(moduleAexportableVar);
commonFunction();
moduleAexportableFunc();
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglifyjs = require('gulp-uglifyjs');

// сначала конвертируем в ES5
gulp.task('babel', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/es2015/*.js')               
        .pipe(babel({ presets: ['es2015'] }))    
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
// по окончании таска ещё бы вызвать сборку buildjs...
});

gulp.task('buildjs', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/js/*.js')
    // соберём модули в один файл. Но как? Понятно, что одной конкатенации не достаточно.
        .pipe(uglifyjs()) // минифицируем выходной файл
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));
})
```

---

### Вопрос

Как следует исправить `gulpfile.js`, чтобы при запуске в один таск конвертировать файлы в **ES5** (папка с **/js**) и собрать их в **bundle.js**?

Comment: [How to run Gulp tasks sequentially one after the other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31329150/2881286)

Comment: Для бандлов нужен, например, вебпак\бабелифай\роллап.
Из галпа можно вызывать вебпак, который будет модули паковать в бандл.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за комментарий, но задача данного вопроса - показать пример, с которого могут начать свой проект веб-разработчики, которые никогда не имели дело со сборкой ES6-модулей. Если Вас не затруднит, дополните пожалуйста `gulpfile.js` до рабочего примера, а какие пакеты устанавливать - приведите консольные команды npm (впрочем, все пакеты можно установить в одну команду).

Comment: пример можно взять здесь - https://github.com/verekia/js-stack-from-scratch. Упрости сам пожалуйста и размести здесь

Comment: Вы наверное не поняли, раз просите показать gulpfile. С gulp, если и можно решить как-то Вашу задачу, это будет совсем не традиционный способ, а традиционный способ не требует gulp. Поэтому верный ответ не может быть в тему этого вопроса. Но с другой стороны, лично я знаю способ как сделать сборку с одним только gulp, но рассказывать о нем не буду, так как лично так не делал и не уверен что это будет работать правильно, хотя и уверен что будет правильно процентов на 90%.

Comment: 1.  Промежуточная папка не нужна. 2. Вопрос сводится к "как задать порядок обработки файлов галпом".

Comment: Мне не нравится постановка вопроса если честно, gulp это просто таск менеджер, если вы хотите полноценно рулить сборкой, областями видимости очень рекомендую вебпак, решать сборку es6 gulp'om обреченно на провал при росте проекта

Comment: gulp прекрасно подходит (посредством [gulp-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel) к примеру) для транспиляции, склейки, минификации и всего остального. Другое дело, что вебпак вроде как помоднее.

Comment: Вообще, я бы хотел оптимизировать количество инструментов для веб-разработки. Но раз уж такая ситуация, что без webpac никак - можете завершить пример с использованием webpac. Я потом подредактирую вопрос, чтобы тематически подогнать его под Ваш ответ.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu если это соответствует вопросу могу расписать как я большую часть этих задач решаю через первый вебпак, без галпа. Я разве что промежуточных es-5 файлов не делаю и если надо отлаживаюсь сразу в бандле.

Comment: Хорошо, напишите пожалуйста. Мне вообще галп нужен для компиляции sass, а так же минификации и конкатенации css и js.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu webpack имеет sass-loader, а минификация --optimize-minimize :) очень маленький конфиг получится.